# Gluon Sample, HelloFX Giving Build Error, Failed to execute goal

Tags: sample, gluon

I have downloaded the Gluon-Samples from GitHub. I am running NetBeans 12.4 with graalvm-ce-java16-21.2.0 installed as my default JDK. When I run the sample HelloFX, build failed is reported with the message "Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) on project hellofx". I have no idea how to fix this. Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

I would also like to if there could be any problems running this gluon-sample with graalvm-ce-java16-21.2.0, since Gluon uses GraalVm substrate -- is it OK to have both in use, Gluon via maven (pom.xml) and the GraalVM locally installed?

Additionally, as a next step, I would like to add java-javascript interoperability to the Gluon sample HelloFX. How exactly would I do this?

Stack Trace:

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:982)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:929)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:457)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

Comment: You can start by posting the full stacktrace error you get, including the command line you are running.

Comment: Sorry, Jose, I will submit a stack trace as soon as I figure out how. This comment box won't hold it.

Comment: Just Edit your question, appending the content you need.

Comment: OK, stack trace entered, thank you.

Comment: Make sure you add the command you are running, like `mvn gluonfx:run`?

Comment: Thanks Jose, I really had no idea I needed to urn that from commanline. I thought it work from within the NetBeans IDE with menu Run/Run Project. Can I ask a few more questions here while I've got you?

Comment: You can run from NetBeans too, but you need to run the `gluonfx` goals. Yes, go ahead. If needed edit your question to add the questions and provide required  details

Comment: Answer accepted. Thank you, you hit the nail right on the head! I simply was not aware I needed to run the program from a terminal commandline -- it worked just fine. Thanks again.

Comment: OK, additional questions added to original, THANKS.

Comment: About GraalVM based on JDK16, there might be some issues (i.e removal of [sunec library](https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/issues/976)) that require a new version of Gluon Substrate, but that shouldn't take long.

Comment: About Java/JS, that can be done, of course. You might want to have a look at this  project: https://github.com/lazar-mitrovic/GraalVMREPL